# How to prove the following inequality? (related to no-arbitrage conditions)

Tags: inequality, finance

I'm working through a practice book on mathematical finance, but struggling to prove part of a question on no-arbitrage conditions.

In the problem, I'm first given $K_1 < K_2 < K_3 $. Then, the book claims that the following relationship: $x_1 (S - K_1) - x_2 (S - K_2) + x_3 (S- K_3) \geq 0, \forall S \geq 0$,

holds if and only if the two conditions are satisfied:
$x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_1 (K_3 - K_1) - x_2 (K_3 - K_2) \geq 0$.

For the life of me I can't seem to prove why this is the case! I know it should be basic algebra but I'm really struggling for some reason. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: @RRL I tried to answer the question as it's stated, but was only able to prove the "if" part always holding in the case where $K_3 \le 0$. Now I understand why I wasn't able to succeed as I know nothing about arbitrage so I didn't realize the correct form of using $\left(S - K_j\right)^{+}$ instead. Since I didn't answer the intended question, and I don't think there's much value for anybody to read my solution (as you say, "this is nonsense"), I am deleting it.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Nonsense means there is no such arbitrage condition for forward contracts with nonnegative forward price.  The question itself is not nonsense.  It still takes some effort to prove the conditions. Others may find this useful -- although it is entirely up you. Undelete and I will give it an upvote.

Comment: @RRL Thanks for the comment & support. I only proved part of it, but perhaps it might be of some use for a few people. As you requested, I have undeleted my solution. Also, I am going to add a comment at the top that it's trying to answer the question as stated, not as it was intended.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: I would not get too concerned. There are relatively few questions here with the finance tag and many are elementary (compound interest, etc.) QuantitativeFinance.SE is usually the best place to ask, but I am always happy when something interesting comes up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will make sense for a portfolio of three call options with common expiry and with strike prices $0 < K_1 < K_2 < K_3$, where we are long $x_1 > 0$ options struck at $K_1$, **short** $x_2 > 0$ options struck at $K_2$ and long $x_3> 0$ options struck at $K_3$.

The payoff of this option portfolio at expiration for underlying price $S$ is

$$V(S) = x_1(S-K_1)^+ - x_2(S - K_2)^+ + x_3(S - K_3)^+$$

where $(S-K_j)^+ = \max(S-K_j,0)$ the payoff of a standard European call option.

For $0 \leqslant S \leqslant K_1$ we have $V(s) = 0$.

For $K_1 \leqslant S \leqslant K_2$ we have $V(S) = x_1(S - K_1) \geqslant 0$.

For $K_2 \leqslant S \leqslant K_3$ we have $V(S) = x_1(S - K_1) - x_2(S- K_2)$. This is a linear function joining the points $(\,K_2,\,x_1(K_2 - K_1)\,)$ and $(\,K_3,\,x_1(K_3-K_1)- x_2(K_3-K_2)\,)$.

Consequently we have $V(S) \geqslant 0$ for $K_2 \leqslant S \leqslant K_3$ if and only if

$$\tag{*}x_1(K_3-K_1)- x_2(K_3-K_2) \geqslant 0$$

For $S \geqslant K_3$ we have

$$V(S) = x_1(S- K_1) - x_2(X- K_2) + x_3(S- K_3) \\ = x_1(K_3-K_1)- x_2(K_3-K_2) +(x_1 - x_2 + x_3)(S - K_3),$$

and assuming that inequality (*) holds we have $V(S) \geqslant 0$ for all $S \geqslant K_3$ if and only if

$$\tag{**} x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \geqslant 0$$

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!! This all makes sense now! You're certainly right about the payoffs, it's obvious now to me that it's a typo. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidLoungani: You're very welcome. Glad it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Note what you state seems to require that $K_3 \le 0$. I later found that this is due to the question statement not quite being correct. Please read RRL's answer for a solution to the question as intended. Nonetheless, the following does prove part of the conditions for options, but not arbitrage.

Using this, note that

$$x_1\left(S - K_1\right) - x_2\left(S - K_2\right) + x_3\left(S - K_3\right) \ge 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

becomes after expanding the terms, collecting all those using $S$ and factoring it out to get that

$$S\left(x_1 - x_2 + x_3\right) - x_1 K_1 + x_2 K_2 - x_3 K_3 \ge 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

To show the "if" part, if

$$x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \ge 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

then

$$S\left(x_1 - x_2 + x_3\right) \ge 0 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

based on $S \ge 0$. With the second condition,

$$x_1\left(K_3 - K_1\right) - x_2\left(K_3 - K_2\right) \ge 0 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

expanding it, collecting the terms using $K_3$ and then factoring out $K_3$, gives

$$-x_1 K_1 + x_2 K_2 + K_3\left(x_1 - x_2\right) \ge 0 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

From \eqref{eq3}, and assuming that $K_3 \le 0$, we get

$$x_1 - x_2 \ge -x_3 \Rightarrow K_3\left(x_1 - x_2\right) \le -K_3 x_3 \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Reversing the inequality shows this can be substituted into \eqref{eq6} to give that

$$-x_1 K_1 + x_2 K_2 - x_3 K_3 \ge 0 \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

Putting \eqref{eq4} and \eqref{eq8} together gives \eqref{eq2}. Note I didn't use anything regarding the relationship of $K_1$ or $K_2$ in terms of $K_3$ here. As for the requirement for $K_3 \le 0$, note that if $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, then \eqref{eq3} requires that $x_3 \ge 0$. Setting $S = 0$ causes \eqref{eq2} to become

$$0 - 0 + 0 - x_3 K_3 \ge 0 \tag{9}\label{eq9}$$

but if $x_3 \gt 0$, then $K_3 \leq 0$. As the OP has stated in a comment to this answer that

> the $K$'s represent different "strike prices" which would in fact generally be greater than $0$

there must be some other conditions or restrictions I'm not aware of, or possibly one of the statements is not presented correctly. For now, this is the best I can do here.

For the "only if" part, I believe the easiest way to show it would possibly be to provide an example where one of \eqref{eq3} or \eqref{eq5} don't hold, then \eqref{eq2} doesn't hold either.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I don't think we can assume the K's are less than 0. It's not explicitly stated in the problem, but the K's represent different "strike prices" which would in fact generally be greater than 0.

Comment: @DavidLoungani Thanks for the additional information. I edited the answer to give an explicit example that shows what you're asking only works in general if $K_3 \leq 0$. Thus, as I stated, there must be some other conditions or restrictions, or something is wrong. Please check to see if that is the case. Regardless, you could likely use similar techniques to what I've shown to solve this, so perhaps you can do it on your own. Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks John, I follow your argument and I think I'm going to actually reach out to the textbook authors to see what they have to say. As you mentioned, I'm guessing there is some implicit assumption which is being left unstated.

Comment: @DavidLoungani You are welcome. Note that nothing is stated about the $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, so it seems strange that they are used unless they have some specific meaning. I have a feeling that there are some additional conditions on these values which will cause everything to work properly.

Comment: @DavidLoungani I see now why my work didn't solve your problem appropriately. With the appropriate additional conditions that RRL states, everything will work then, as shown in RRL's answer.